# Frequency count per observation in R

Tags: r, frequency

I am trying to do a frequency count of a categorical variable (i.e., upper division class) per case in a dataset that is currently in long format. I am using R.

Current data set:
Student_ID   Class  UD_class 
111        PSY 400   1 
111        ENG 310   0 
111         EE 510  1 

I would like to conver it to a frame that looks like this: 
Student_ID   UD_class
111        2 

I tried using this code and this is providing me wrong frequencies: 
data.frame(table(data$Student_ID, data$UD_class)) 

Any suggestions on how I can do this in R? Thank you!

Comment: yes. used data.frame(table(data$Student_ID, data$UD_class)) and it is not providing correct frequencies, and it is also giving me an extra variable with all frequency counts of 0.

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me quickly point out that if one of the answers below solved your issue, you can accept the answer that you found most helpful by clicking on the v sign next to the start of the answer. This way the person earns credit and others can see that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 with(data[data$UD_class==1,], data.frame(table(Student_ID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `as.data.frame` instead of `data.frame`. To maintain your column headings use the `with` function: `as.data.frame(with(df, table(StID, ud_class)))`